# Servlet file uploader

Tags: java, error-handling, network-file-transfer, servlets

I think this code looks ugly, especially with the multiple try-catch blocks, but I don't know how to rewrite it:

```
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url,@RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletResponse response) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
             inputStream =  new URL(url).openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot open stream by url=[{}]", url);
            try {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Cannot open stream by url=" + url);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                LOG.error("Cannot send error");
            }
            return null;
        }
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
            byte[] binary = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, binary);
            UploadedMultipartFile multipartFile = new UploadedMultipartFile(file, file.length(), "jpg",
                    "formParameter", fileName);
            MultipartFileWrapper multipartFileWrapper = new MultipartFileWrapper();
            multipartFileWrapper.setMultipartFile(multipartFile);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(multipartFileWrapper);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot save file [{}] from [{}]",fileName, url);
            try {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Cannot save file " + fileName);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                LOG.error("Cannot send error");
            }
            return null;
        }
        return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Two `try` blocks in a method is a smell IMO: your method is *trying* to *do two things*, which implies it's *not* doing *one and only one thing*.

Let's see:

- We open a stream from a given url and if all goes well we have an `inputStream` to work with.

  - Or things go bad, and we log an error, and then try to send an error response before we return `null` - if returning the error response failed, we log and still return `null`.
- We use the stream to create a new file, and return a hard-coded string on success, or `null` on failure.

That alone looks like a bit of reusable functionality that should be extracted into its own method: one whose responsibility would be to send an error response:

```
void sendErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse response, string message) {
    try {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        LOG.error("An error occurred while sending error response: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Next, you need a function that takes a `url` and gives you an `inputStream`.

```
InputStream openStreamFromUrl(string url, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream result;
    try {
        result = new URL(url).openStream();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        string message = "Cannot open stream for url=" + url;
        LOG.error(message);
        sendErrorResponse(response, message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So calling this `openStreamFromUrl` function either returns a valid and opened `InputStream`, or a `null` reference. This means we can now do this:

```
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url,@RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream inputStream = openStreamFromUrl(url, response);
    if (inputStream == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // handle file upload
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try-with-resources are a great way to isolate and also nest exception handling. In your case, a nested try-catch would be best.

Additionally, a function to handle returning the error-state to the client would help a lot too.

Consider the following:

```
private static final String handleError(HttpServletResponse response, String message) {

    LOG.error(message);
    try {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        LOG.error("Cannot send error");
    }
    return null;

}
```

Then use that as follows (note, read the InputStream before opening the writer... it avoids unnecessary work in the event the input stream fails part way through...:

```
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url, @RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();) {

        byte[] binary = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, binary);
            UploadedMultipartFile multipartFile = new UploadedMultipartFile(file, file.length(), "jpg",
                    "formParameter", fileName);
            MultipartFileWrapper multipartFileWrapper = new MultipartFileWrapper();
            multipartFileWrapper.setMultipartFile(multipartFile);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(multipartFileWrapper);

            return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return handleError(response, "Cannot save file " + fileName + " from " + url);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return handleError(response, "Cannot open stream by url=" + url);
    }
}
```